How to remove alignment options in the CKEditor 5 of TYPO3 12?
How to exclude certain alignment options in your own preset?
Although I have not specified "right" and "justify", they are still shown:
imports:
    - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml' }
    - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml' }
    - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml' }

editor:
  config:
    alignment:
      options:
        - { name: 'left', className: 'text-left' }
        - { name: 'center', className: 'text-center' }

    toolbar:
      items:
        - bold
        - italic
        - alignment



You can activate the desired toolbar items separately (JustifyLeft, JustifyCenter, JustifyRight, JustifyBlock ) instead of all at once (alignment):
imports:
    - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml' }
    - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml' }
    - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml' }

editor:
  config:
    alignment:
      options:
        - { name: 'left', className: 'text-left' }
        - { name: 'center', className: 'text-center' }
        - { name: 'right', className: 'text-right' }
        - { name: 'justify', className: 'text-justify' }

    toolbar:
      items:
        - bold
        - italic
        #- alignment
        - JustifyLeft
        - JustifyCenter
        #- JustifyRight
        #- JustifyBlock

Individual buttons are shown in this way:


For anyone else wondering:
You can't remove the justify option while keeping the alignment dropdown.
Typo3 decided to add an undocumented "compatibility layer" with the class CKEditor5Migrator which automatically converts old configuration options like "toolbarGroups" to CKEditor 5 configuration.
And it also always adds the classNames for all four alignment options.
